# Can you give me an example of a magnet with more than 2 poles?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm just looking for a magnet with three, four, ... poles. I will not be able to find monopoles (because nobody found them yet) but I also know there is a way to make a magnet with three poles for example, and I would like to have an example of it please.

Comment: Please show your source for a magnet with three poles.

Comment: https://www.windows2universe.org/physical_science/magnetism/magnetic_multipole_fields.html&edu=elem

Comment: Are you asking for _a single_ magnet with more than two poles?

Comment: yes (i mean i don't want 3 magnets put together for example)

Comment: So two erstwhile editors who missed "founded"...

Comment: Unless you're talking about elementary particles, the idea of a "single" magnet is not well-defined.

Answer (score 9):

Magnets don’t really have two poles, despite high-school physics textbooks sometimes using this misleading terminology. They have *no* poles, because there are no magnetic monopoles anywhere in nature, or at least none ever observed. All magnetic field lines, including those of permanent magnets, form continuous loops and do not end on poles. This is what

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0$$

means!

The so-called “poles” of a permanent magnet are simply the places on the surface of the magnet where the looping field lines emerge from, and re-enter into, the magnetic material.

Comment: If you look at H the pole concept works though (even beyond high school physics), doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know of any single piece of magnet having more than two poles. However, if you consider the planet as a whole as a magnet, [Uranus and Neptune](https://ase.tufts.edu/cosmos/view_picture.asp?id=1004) have a large additional quadrupole component in addition to the dipole part of their magnetic field. [Saturn's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Saturn#Magnetospheric_regions) also has quadrupole, octupole and higher components, though they are much weaker than the dipole.

There are models generalizing the dipole model of the Earth's magnetic field to multipoles. A measurement of the geomagnetic field at any given point and time consists of a superposition of fields from different sources which could give rise to multipoles. Simplest of them is dipole, followed by quadrupole, octupole and so on. A detailed description with the strength of each pole of Earth's magnetic field collected from [IGRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Geomagnetic_Reference_Field) can be seen [here](http://helios.fmi.fi/~juusolal/geomagnetism/Lectures/Chapter4_multipole.pdf).

[image]

Also, one can construct a [quadrupole magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_magnet) by placing two identical bar magnets parallel to each other such that the north pole of one is next to the south of the other and vice-versa. This arrangement of four magnets will not have the dipole terms and the lowest significant terms in the field equations from [multipole expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) would be quadrupole terms. Also, there are [Helmholtz coils](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/helmholtz.html#c1) used in the laboratory to generate a nearly uniform magnetic field having a quadrupole magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

Those fields that appear in the link you provided are not produced by a single magnet. You cannot have a magnet with more than two poles.

Those multipole fields are generated by multiple coils arranged in some particular ways.

If you want to know more about how to produce such kind of magnet fields, on the webpage of CERN there is a lot of information or on Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_magnet)

Comment: Single coils can have quadrupole moments.  And unless you are talking about elementary particles, the concept of a "single magnet" is an illusory one.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before any location where field lines emerge is North and where field lines enter South pole area. A piece of ferromagnetic material may consist of many regions of varying shape that differ in the direction of magnetization. Where these are at the surface a pattern of magnetic field lines will cross the surface and a pattern of alternating poles can be argued to occur. Any number of poles is allowed as long as the total flux through the surface vanishes. This excludes a single pole.

In practice, for a strong magnet you want N and S to be maximally separated and two poles will give you that result.

Comment: can you give me an example with 3 poles?

Comment: @jeanmarc if you don't mind a V shape.

Answer (score 0):

**There has been no need for physicists to introduce the concept of *three or more kinds of poles* in order to describe the flow of current through closed loops (eg: a bar magnet)**

Magnets are actually current flowing in closed loops. This is what physically happens inside a magnet. However before this fact was discovered by Ampere in 1820s, many physicists (Coulomb, Poisson, etc) interpreted it as two kinds of magnetic charges residing at the two ends of a bar magnet.

From the law of force between two current loops, one can see that the two loops (elements of loops) attract if current is flowing in same direction and repel if current is flowing in opposite directions. Thus if one end of two bar magnets ($N_1$ and $N_2$) are brought close, and if the directions of currents at the ends are same, there will be an attraction and we naively say: (the ends of the bar magnet or its poles) are same. Now if you bring the other end of first magnet ($S_1$) close to $N_2$, apparently, then the directions of currents at the ends are opposite, and there will be a repulsion and we naively say: poles are opposite.

With that said, the pole model of magnets is a valid model and it works almost perfectly and it was used by several physicists even after Ampere (eg: Maxwell), even though this pole model is used little now-a-days.

Answer (score -4):

based on your reference, there are two different things you should know, magnet poles and magnetic field poles ?? as far as i know, magnet can be ONLY two poles . maybe there s some magnet in Neptune with 3 poles. maybe.